# Git workflow: what to do about changes from another developer that is not using Git

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-post-receive

I have set up Git on the production server with a post receive hook.  This allows me to use ‘git push production master’ to deploy the master branch to production.

This project also has a web developer that is modifying pages, but she is using dreamweaver/ftp to deploy those pages to production. She is not using git or github.

We discovered today that my deployment post-receive hook is overwriting the files that she changed. This was unexpected as I was thinking that the hook would only overwrite/merge changed files.

There are number of fixes to this that I think of and I am looking for more ideas:

1. She gets me a list of changed files and I pull those down from production and update the repo (kludgy)
2. We use github and give her access to the private repo (Not really an option as this developer is not an employee of my company - security issues)
3. Untrack (and add to .gitignore) all of the files/directories that she might touch, or makes changes to.  This may be viable as I am really only responsible for a few areas. Also she is updating just a few files, 10 at the most. UPDATE: This does not work.  If I untrack and gitignore the files in question they get deleted from the production server on 'git push production master'
4. Modify the post receive hook to ignore files on the server that have been changed.

As I type this, I am thinking that option 3 is the best. I would simply untrack and add to .gitignore all files she makes changes to - she would provide me a list of those files.  I would have to test this with the post-receive hook. UPDATE -Nope this was not a solution.  See #3 above.

If there is better way to address this, let me know.

Here is the post-receive hook code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 2. Only deploy if master branch was pushed
if (branch =~ /master$/) == nil
    puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../')
`GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"
```

Comment: How do you get your developers changes in to your repository right now?  It doesn't seem like that is happening right now.  Also why are you letting her make changes directly to production if you don't trust her to have access to your github repo?

Comment: Exactly. The only clean way to get this resolved is to get her to contribute to the same repo and use the same workflow that you are using. Another option would be to separate the files into different repos or directories. But again, it's a questionable practice to allow some people to change things in production, bypassing your standard workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree that the situation is less than ideal. My company does not want to allow her to use the repo - security issue.  This project is short term, so I am looking for an alternative that does not include adding her to the repo.  Also, she does not know how to use Git and there is no time to get her trained up. So given these constraints, I am looking for the best/safest way to ensure that my push to production script does not overwrite the files she made changes too.

Comment: Get her to update a different server (DEV), not PROD. Then you take the changes from there and merge them into the repo. Leave the PROD server alone as far as possible :-)

Comment: Good suggestion regarding using a different server.  Lets assume that spinning up another server for this customer is not going to be possible in the time frame and budget we have.  What then would be the best option to prevent overwrite of the files she changes in production.

Comment: How is she not allowed to use the repo but allowed to make changes to Production? It makes no sense from a security standpoint

Comment: @nwinkler your suggestion is the best, put it as an answer so it can be upvoted

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz This project was not managed in Git prior to my recent involvement.  They used dreamweaver/ftp to deploy to production. I created a repo for my own use. Unfortunately the constraints of this project are such that the outside developer will not be using git.  I am looking for a solution where I can use a deployment script to push to production that does not overwrite or delete files in production modfied by the other developer.  I realize it is less than ideal and not even close to best practices.

Comment: @dtburgess Since the project started without git and now the authoritative source is production itself, you should not rely on your local repo to freely push since you are the one that is overwritting the files. Instead you should bring the changes from production to your local repo, so you can do the merge yourself and then push

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Thanks, that is what I suspected - that I would have to incorporate the other developer's changes in my repo then push.  What would be the most efficient and automated way to do so? Currently my solution is to pull down the files with FTP and manually up them in my repo directory.

Comment: @dtburgess Letting the designer use Git is a "security issue", but they can write straight to production? Using unencrypted ftp?!  It sounds like you already realize how absurd that is and are trying to make things better, so take this as consolatory indignation.